# Show errors in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I made consider_all_requests_local to option true in development.rb file.

> config.consider_all_requests_local       = true

My development and production environments are linked to aibrake debugging system. The problem is when i set consider_all_requests_local as true, I still can't see any errors in my browser. What I get is this: http://postimg.org/image/l9k0zjkwp/

Have any ideas why I can't see errors in my browser?

Comment: Did you restart your server after that change?

Comment: Yes I did restart server.

Answer (score 1):

`true` is already the default in `development` mode. You will have to set it to `false`, so that Rails considers even local requests to not be local:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

From the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration):

> `config.consider_all_requests_local` is a flag. If `true` then any error will cause detailed debugging information to be dumped in the HTTP response, and the `Rails::Info` controller will show the application runtime context in `/rails/info/properties`. `true` by default in `development` and `test` environments, and `false` in `production` mode. For finer-grained control, set this to `false` and implement `local_request?` in controllers to specify which requests should provide debugging information on errors.